# Excel: How to strip search terms from a cell (referring URL)

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I have cells that contain a referring URL of visitors who entered my websites.

this URL always has a different lenght, but it's constant format is such that the search term always shows up between `p=` or `q=` in the start and `&` afterwards, possibly with `+` or `%20` inside as spaces when the search term included more than one work.

Example:

```
1. http://www.bing.com/search?q=word1%20word2%20word3&qs=AS&sk=HS1&sc=8-6
2. http://search.yahoo.com/search?fr=ipad&p=word1+word2&pcarrier=&pmcc=&pmnc=
```

search term for #1: "word1 word2 word3"

search term for #2: "word1 word2"

So these is what I really want to see left in these cells.

Is there a way to do so? (that would handles the above multiple situations)

Comment: How about text to columns using the & and/or = as delimiters?  Otherwise it is macro writing time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, you can do something like this -

```
=MID(A1,FIND("=",A1)+1,FIND("&",A1)-FIND("=",A1)-1)
```

It will print the string between the first `=` and the first `&`.

Comment: Thanks, this is working but there can be many `=` in the cell, I need only either `p=` or `q=`, so how can I define both?
I need something like:
`=MID(P8,SEARCH(["p="]OR["q="],P8)+2,SEARCH("&",P8)-SEARCH(["p="]OR["q="],P8)-2)` but don't know how to define such an `OR`

Comment: @rockyraw [check this out](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/601195-check-multiple-text-strings-cell.html); I think, though, with URLs, only the first `=` should be the search query.

Comment: Didn't manage to implement the example in that link :/

Comment: @rockyraw the issue is `OR` returns `true` or `false`, so you must search for something, if true, then multiply true (1) by what you found, if false multiply by 0

Comment: I don't want anything to return false or true then, I'm just trying to illustrate that I need the exact formuala you gave to handle two possible values rather then one :)

Comment: @rockyraw right, so you can't use `or`. You'll need nested `IF` statements around your `FIND` functions. Give it a try.

Comment: according to [this](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/if_nested.php) Nested IF suits true/flase as well...

Comment: @rockyraw no it evaluates for true/false, then returns what you tell it to depending on the test.