# How to use different formula in case of en error?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I want to run the following formulas on a cell, in this order,
in case the previous formula returns an error.

`=MID(P2,SEARCH("q=",P2)+2,SEARCH("&",P2)-SEARCH("q=",P2)-2)`

`=MID(P2,SEARCH("p=",P2)+2,SEARCH("&",P2)-SEARCH("p=",P2)-2)`

`=RIGHT(P2,LEN(P2)-FIND("q=",P2)-1)`

`=RIGHT(P2,LEN(P2)-FIND("p=",P2)-1)`

How can I define this?

Comment: It's not clear what you want.  Are you asking for a single formula for a cell that evaluates P2 for multiple conditions and returns the last good value based on the order you've stated?

Comment: Why didn't you just stick to your [other question](http://superuser.com/questions/817837/excel-how-to-strip-search-terms-from-a-cell-referring-url).  Asking a second question without the previous details leads to confusion.

Comment: Nevermind, I've manged to do it with multiple `IFERROR` inside an `IFERORR`: `=IFERROR(MID(R167,SEARCH("q=",R167)+2,SEARCH("&",R167)-SEARCH("q=",R167)-2),IFERROR(MID(R167,SEARCH("p=",R167)+2,SEARCH("&",R167)-SEARCH("p=",R167)-2),IFERROR(RIGHT(R167,LEN(R167)-FIND("q=",R167)-1),IFERROR(RIGHT(R167,LEN(R167)-FIND("p=",R167)-1),zzzzzz))))`

Comment: For others who might have the same type of problem or people who might spend time trying to re-answer your question, why don't you put your solution in an answer and mark it solved (you are allowed to answer your own question).

Comment: If your question(s) are solved, be sure to click the check mark next to the answer to indicate it's been answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've manged to do it with multiple IFERROR inside an IFERORR:

`=IFERROR(MID(R167,SEARCH("q=",R167)+2,SEARCH("&",R167)-SEARCH("q=",R167)-2),IFE‌​RROR(MID(R167,SEARCH("p=",R167)+2,SEARCH("&",R167)-SEARCH("p=",R167)-2),IFERROR(R‌​IGHT(R167,LEN(R167)-FIND("q=",R167)-1),IFERROR(RIGHT(R167,LEN(R167)-FIND("p=",R16‌​7)-1),zzzzzz))))`

Comment: Try to test only the function that may result in an error instead of testing the entire expression. So maybe you can just "iferror" the search expression.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `IFERROR()` formula is a good option. However, you should avoid using one huge formula, it's bad practice and if your formula plays up it'll be too big to debug. I'd opt for this in four separate columns

**A2**

```
=IFERROR(MID(P2,SEARCH("q=",P2)+2,SEARCH("&",P2)-SEARCH("q=",P2)-2),0)
```

**B2**

```
=IF(A2=0,0,MID(P2,SEARCH("p=",P2)+2,SEARCH("&",P2)-SEARCH("p=",P2)-2))
```

**C2**

```
=IF(B2=0,0,RIGHT(P2,LEN(P2)-FIND("q=",P2)-1),0)
```

**D2**

```
=IF(C2=0,0,RIGHT(P2,LEN(P2)-FIND("p=",P2)-1),0)
```

And then finally a simple `SUM` will suffice

**E2**

```
=SUM(A2:D2)
```

You could hide/ group columns **A** to **D**, but this way you can see how the answer